# Задача с сортировкой массива JavaScript

Tags: javascript, массивы

Задача: Найти в массиве нули, удалить с данного индекса и добавить в конец массива.

```
var moveZeros = function (arr) {
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ )
    {
     if(arr[i] == 0 )
      {
             arr.splice(i, 1);
             arr.push(0);
      }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Данные входные значения:

`Expected: '[1,2,1,1,3,1,0,0,0,0]'` ответ правильный в одном случае, а в других вариантах появляться ноль в массиве. Подскажите как так получается:

> *Expected: '[9,9,1,2,1,1,3,1,9,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]', instead got: '[9,0,9,1,2,1,1,3,1,9,0,0,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]'*
>
> Expected: *'["a","b","c","d",1,1,3,1,9,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]', instead got: '["a",0,"b","c","d",1,1,3,1,9,0,0,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]'*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы пропускаете ноль, если он оказывается в месте с индексом `i` в результате сдвига. Пример - два ноля подряд в середине массива.